# Map implementation with duplicate keys in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to have a map with duplicate keys. Is there such a map in Dart or a utility library that has this functionality?

I'm using the following get a count of items:

```
myList.forEach(
      (element) {
        if (!myMap.containsKey(element)) {
          myMap[element] = 1;
        } else {
          myMap[element] += 1;
        }
      },
    );
```

then convert keys/values to lists: Need to switch key/values...

```
final keys = myMap.keys.toList();
final itemSpit = keys.map((e) => e.toString().split('§º')).toList();
final values = myMap.values.toList();
```

put it in a map

```
final map = Map();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      map[values[i]] = itemSpit[i];
    }
```

Obviously the keys are overridden in the for loop.

then
iterate over map (Put keys/values in flutter widgets)

```
final cells = map.entries
        .map((e) => ........
```

THe first method increases the value count if there's a duplicate value. So I have this.  ... {breadwhitelarge: 3, cornyellowsmall:5 ..etc..}

I then have to split the strings and have output like this

```
5 bread white large
3 corn yellow small
```

Comment: What value should be returned when asked for a key there are multiple times?

Comment: I just want to iterate over the map... I have a count stored as a key

Comment: I think it is easier if you show an example of a data structure you want to represent in Dart and how you want to iterate over it.

Comment: I've seen it in other languages. Was just wondering how to do it in Dart

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea of what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to switch key/value?

Comment: Could you not use a `List` as value and put stuff inside this list each time you have another value for the same key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of defining a map which allows duplicated keys you can instead create a `Map<K,List<V>>` like this example:

```
void main() {
  final map = <String, List<int>>{};

  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 1', 1);
  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 1', 2);
  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 2', 3);
  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 1', 4);
  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 2', 5);
  addValueToMap(map, 'Test 3', 6);

  print(map); // {Test 1: [1, 2, 4], Test 2: [3, 5], Test 3: [6]}
}

void addValueToMap<K, V>(Map<K, List<V>> map, K key, V value) =>
    map.update(key, (list) => list..add(value), ifAbsent: () => [value]);
```

You can then ask for a given key and get a list of all values connected to this key.

Comment: Thanks, looks good..I'll mark it correct tomorrow if it works...too tired now!

Answer (score 2):

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) provides a [`MultiMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html) class with [`List`-based](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/ListMultimap-class.html) and [`Set`-based](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/SetMultimap-class.html) implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just create the Flutter widgets directly from the first map?

```dart
var widgets = [for (var e in myMap.entries) MyWidget(
  count: e.value,
  strings: [... e.key.split("§º")])];
```

Building the intermediate map seems to be what is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example map has duplicate keys

```
withDuplicateKey() {
  List<dynamic> demoList = [
    {1},
    {2},
    {3},
    {1}
  ];
  var toRemove = {};
  demoList.forEach((e) {
    toRemove.putIfAbsent(e, () => e);
  });
  print(toRemove.keys.toList());
}
```

```
output is ( printed list of key )
 [{1}, {2}, {3}, {1}]
```